# SOLVED Having problems returning multiple values in a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

Hello i'm getting this error when trying to access values from a function.

```
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: createInvoice is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\index.js:101:63)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\InteractionCreate.js:97:12)
    at Object.module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:354:31)
    at WebSocketManager.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:238:12)
    at WebSocketManager.emit (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:1103:51)
    at WebSocketShard.emit (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\@vladfrangu\async_event_emitter\dist\index.js:282:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot\node_modules\@discordjs\ws\dist\index.js:938:14)
Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:384:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)

C:\Users\Utente\Desktop\sito\InvoiceBot>
```

This is the function where i'm returning from:

```
function createInvoice(item_name, note_message, quantity, cost, payer_email){ 

    let create_invoice_json = {
        "merchant_info": {
            "email": config.emailAddress,
            "business_name": config.business_name,
        },
        "billing_info": [
        {
        "email": payer_email,
        }
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "name": item_name,
                "quantity": quantity,
                "unit_price": {
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "value": cost,
                }
            },
        ],
        
        "note": note_message,
        }

    paypal.invoice.create(create_invoice_json, function (error, invoice) {
        if (error) {
            throw error;
        } else {
            //console.log(invoice)
            return [invoice.id, invoice.status, invoice.billing_info[0],  invoice.items[0], invoice.items[1], invoice.invoice_date, invoice.total_amount[1]] 
        }
    });
}
```

And this is how i want to access the values:

```
 const [id, status, payer, item, q, date, price] = createInvoice(item_name, note_message, quantity, cost, payer_email)
```

I think it should be correct but its returning me that error...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/is_not_iterable

Comment: Have you checked what your `createInvoice` call actually returns? The `return` statement is inside of the callback function you are passing to `paypal.invoice.create`, so I very much doubt that it even makes it's way further up.

Comment: the return is okay, its just getting the value that gives an error

Comment: Okay, then see the explanation I linked to. A mere plain object, is not an _iterable_ object.

Comment: What is `console.log(createInvoice(item_name, note_message, quantity, cost, payer_email))` looking alike at your end? You do not need to share sensitive data here, if you have anything sensitive in there, just replace it with a dummy value.

Comment: its actually undefined... i just noticed that, then the problem is in the return because the values are not undefined. But why is it undefined the return statement seems correct to me

Comment: @KaoDev your return statement is inside the callback function passed to `paypal.invoice.create` and it's not a return statement of `createInvoice`. Written an answer to elaborate on that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1):

`createInvoice` returns `undefined`, because the `return` statement that we see physically inside of it actually returns values of the callback function passed to `paypal.invoice.create`. You will need to either return something meaningful from `createInvoice` proper, or move the logic that needs the values into the callback.

Comment: wdym? how should i do that practically?

Comment: @KaoDev you can 1. Create an empty array just before you call `paypal.invoice.create(...)`, I will call it `ret`, 2. put an `await` keyword in the line of your `paypal.invoice.create(...)` call, 3. Change the `return` statement to `ret = return [invoice.id, invoice.status, invoice.billing_info[0],  invoice.items[0], invoice.items[1], invoice.invoice_date, invoice.total_amount[1]];` and 4. at the very end of your `createInvoice` function, `return` it as `return ret;`

Comment: i tried that and it returned an empty array, though i solved my problem by doing what i wanted in the callback function! Thanks for helping :D

Comment: @KaoDev happy to help. If the answer led you to the solution, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer. As about the empty array, it seems that you missed step 3. If you are interested about the reason, you might edit your question with the exact code that you tried and message me here.